# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method "leanModal"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone explain me why i got error !?

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://designshack.net/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style_modle.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.leanModal.min.js"></script>
```

And this is All script i using in head :

```
<link href="css/jnice.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="css/jquery.selectbox.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="vidplayer/video-js.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Added to loanModle   -->
<link rel="icon" href="http://designshack.net/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style_modle.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.leanModal.min.js"></script>
<!-- END Added to loanModle END   -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.selectbox-0.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mod_radio.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vidplayer/video.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script>
```

This is my BODY :

```
 <div id="content">
     <center><a href="#loginmodal" class="flatbtn" id="modaltrigger">About Us</a></center>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="loginmodal" style="display:none;">
     <p>Text text text ! <a href="http://Satisfactionscript.pl">Satisfactionscript.pl</a> </p>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#loginform').submit(function(e){
    return false;
  });

  $('#modaltrigger').leanModal({ top: 110, overlay: 0.45, closeButton: ".hidemodal" });
});
```

And "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method "leanModal"  is showing in here :

```
$('#modaltrigger').leanModal({ top: 110, overlay: 0.45, closeButton: ".hidemodal" });
    });
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that `js/jquery.leanModal.min.js` exists and is not returning a 404? Can you browse to it and see the source?

Comment: Also check to ensure that you aren't referencing the jquery script more than once.

Comment: Yes Exist and i see it on browser when i browse it

Answer (score 3):

You're including jQuery twice.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.leanModal.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

Take out the 1.7.2 version and try again.

Edit for clarity: First you include jQuery 1.9.1, and `$` becomes jQuery 1.9.1. Then you load leanModal which becomes a plugin to jQuery 1.9.1. Then you load jQuery 1.7.2, and `$` becomes a brand new jQuery 1.7.2 which does *not* have the leanModal plugin. Then you try to call the leanModal plugin, which no longer exists on `$`.

Comment: I did but then i got errors like this : 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js:18
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'safari' of undefined 

and leanModle still not working

Comment: That is because jQuery 1.9.1 no longer contains `$.browser`, which has `$.msie` and `$.safari`. Either just use jQuery 1.7.2, or include the [browser plugin separately](https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin), or use [jquery-migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) and get your code up to date. [Browser detection is bad](http://css-tricks.com/browser-detection-is-bad/).

Comment: Still nothing ;/ What is other way to use something like this ? can i somehowe use something else to have other nice popup dialog window ?

Comment: What do you mean by "still nothing"? Are you going to use 1.7.2? Did you move the jQuery 1.7.2 script tag to *before* leanModal.js? Is this version of leanModal compatible with jQuery 1.7.2? leanModal definitely works, you've just got some little thing wrong somewhere.

Comment: You saved me time on a headache project today. Thank you!